# Python.NET Serial Events Cause Freeze of GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, python.net, gil

In a python program I'm using for Windows the pythonnet library because I wanted to make use of event based serial communication. These serial communication is used in a GUI application of PyQt5. Below, how I initialize the communication:

```
self.serial_port = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort()
self.serial_port.PortName = self.port_name
self.serial_port.DataReceived += System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(self._receive)
serial_port.Open()

def _receive(self, sender, arg: System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) -> None:
    data = sender.ReadExisting()
    self.received_data.put(data)
```

received_data is a [Queue-Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) of the standard library. Another thread consumes the queue while connected.
Sometimes (without any visible reproducibility) I notice that during communication the GUI suddenly freezes completely. This issue rarely occurs, without any error message.

After some research, I figured out that the serial event uses its own thread. [See under remarks, second last paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). My only thought meanwhile is, that this may do not work properly in a multithreading application in Python because it does not regard the [GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) of Python and may cause undefined behaviour.